# Opening softkeyboard again when entering activity from back button

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-softkeyboard

I use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` in my manifest file to open the softkeyboard when the main activity is launched.

This works great, apart from when i come back to the main activity from another using the back button; The softkeyboard does not reappear.

How do i make the softkeyboard appear when coming back to the main activity?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On back button it just remove the current activity from the stack and show the previous activity that is why softkeyboard is not getting opened . you can override the onKeyDown() method and on back button you can call your activity again.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

        // start your activity again here
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```